# Como referenciar a diretoria atual

Tags: htaccess, variáveis, diretório

A título de exemplo, fazendo uso da variável [`SCRIPT_FILENAME`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) podemos obter o ficheiro solicitado, mas para este problema o que se pretende é obter a diretoria onde se encontra o ficheiro `.htaccess`:

```
# Rewrite the url
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    #DirectorySlash Off
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect when the target isn't an existent file or directory
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ /www/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

A ideia é substituir o `www` por uma variável de forma a que ao mudar o ficheiro `.htaccess` de localização não seja necessário editar o mesmo para alterar a referência.

Em termos práticos, e para este caso especifico, o código em cima é utilizado dentro de uma pasta que se encontra na raiz do alojamento, ou seja, dentro da `public_html`.

A seguinte regra:

```
RewriteRule ^ /www/index.php [L]
```

pode ser:

```
RewriteRule ^ /www2/index.php [L]
```

ou

```
RewriteRule ^ /bubu/index.php [L]
```

## Pergunta

Existe alguma forma de referenciar a diretoria onde o ficheiro `.htaccess` se encontra, mesmo que limitado ao cenário especifico aqui indicado?

Comment: **Nota:** Na [lista de variáveis](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html#Mod_Rewrite_Variables) disponíveis não parece existir nada _pré-feito_ :(

Comment: Eu não mano muito de .htaccess, o meu faz é empurrar tudo pro index.php e ele que se vire (:p), mas o quê que *%{PATH_INFO}* retornaria?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Porção do caminho em uso que vem após o local onde está o `.htaccess` se a memória não me falha.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto faça um teste neste layout: `http://seusite/teste.php/pasta/pasta` (nao precisam existir as pastas, o importante é o teste.php conter um `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` para você ver umas variáveis novas. Some isso com um pouco de imaginação (configurar o server para servir arquivos sem extensão como PHP) e em certos momentos até o `.htaccess` você vai poder deixar de usar.

Comment: Quem sabe num outro momento. Hoje são duas linhas apenas pra direcionar o fluxo pro index.php (que é meu bootstrap) e meu FrontController faz o resto. :D

Comment: @Zuul pouco trabalhei com configurações do apache, mas em ambientes linux e até mesmo em windows usar o `./index.php` significaria que o arquivo estaria no diretório corrento do aplicativo, mas não sei se isso vai funcionar com o apache.

Comment: Olha essa solução http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027343/let-htaccess-rewriterule-redirect-to-a-script-in-current-dir-instead-of-an-e

Comment: Tente usar a variável `{ENV:BASE}`.

Referência:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027343/let-htaccess-rewriterule-redirect-to-a-script-in-current-dir-instead-of-an-e

Comment: @Zuul E se reescrever a `index.php`, sem a `/` no início?

Answer (score 1):

Em sistemas UNIX(Linux, BSD, etc) você utiliza `./` para se referir ao diretório atual.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar regex dentro do .htaccess, o que ficaria algo assim:

```
RewriteRule ^ (\.+)?\/index.php [L]
```

Na expressão estou definindo que pode existir qualquer coisa em qualquer quantidade **ou não** antes do /índex.php.